# trying to connect to oracle database from asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have downloaded from this link (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html) the 2 following zips :

(Version 10.2.0.2)

- instantclient-basic-win-x86-64-10.2.0.2.0-20060503.zip
- instantclient-sqlplus-win-x86-64-10.2.0.2.0-20060503.zip

I extract the content of the 2 zipsin "instantclient".
So at this point I have this :

C:\Users\me\Desktop\oracle\instantclient :

-classes12.jar
-glogin.sql
-oci.dll
-ocijdbc10.dll
-ociw32.dll
-ojdbc14.jar
-orannzsbb10.dll
-oraocci10.dll
-oraociei10.dll
-Orasqlplusic10.dll
-sqlplus.exe

I then modify my "Path" system variable environment by adding "D:\Users\me\Desktop\oracle\instantclient" to it.

Now, when I try to connect to my database from my asp.net application with the following code :

```
String connectionString =     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionKey"].ConnectionString;
            OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
            }
```

I am getting the following exception :
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
and in details I have : {"The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client"}

I don't know what to add to make the connection.

ps : I am sure of the connectionString.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682773/how-to-choose-an-oracle-provider-for-net-application

Comment: I used ODP.NET: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html

Comment: Ok, I have downloaded this version : 64-bit Oracle 10g Release 2 ODAC 10.2.0.3 for Windows x64. I then followed the 2 instructions at the end of the page (unzip and run the setup.exe) But then what I have to do in my asp.net project (do I have to change my previous code or adding a reference in visual parameters)?